# PreLaunchTask could not find the task - Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I am attempting to make a code-workspace that handles a powershell module and a few automation scripts. So for this example my folder structure looks like this -

###### general folder structure

```
- workspace.code-workspace
- README.md
>- .vscode
    - tasks.json
    - install-module-locally.ps1
>- src
    >- Automations
        - Invoke-Test.ps1
    >- Modules
        >- MyModule
            > public
            > private
            - MyModule.psd1
            - MyModule.psm1
```

The public and private folder holds the cmdlets that are used in the PowerShell module, and the module works as expected.

In the `workspace.code-workspace` file I create a launch configuration that attempts to allow the user to execute an `F5` build which will run any file they currently have in focus. In the settings I also have a `preLaunchTask` to run the default task which is supposed to import the module being worked on.

###### workspace.code-workspace

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {},
    "launch": {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "PowerShell",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Current File",
                "script": "${file}",
                "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The `tasks.json` has the following code in it and executes successfully when ran through the `Tasks: Run Task > import-module > Continue without scanning the task output`.

###### tasks.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "import-module",
            "detail": "Imports the module locally for testing individual scripts that would require it without having logic in each script.",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}\\.vscode\\install-module-locally.ps1",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However when I visit a script, for example `Invoke-Test.ps1`, and press `F5`, an error appears stating the task could not be found.

[image: Could not find the task 'import-module'.]

and when I click `Configure Task` it brings me to my `tasks.json` file and highlights the task that I was expecting it to run before executing the current file I was in.

I have been searching and most other questions or github issues don't seem to show a direct relation between an actual issue and the resolution of this problem. I am hoping if I can't eventually answer this myself, that someone else can.

###### github example

Example on [github](https://github.com/lzinga/vscode-tasks-error), if you open the workspace and load the `Invoke-Test.ps1` and press `F5` or build it will show the pop up pictured above.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: I will try to strip the actual code down to a point that I can share it. Not sure how long it will take, but I can hopefully have something to share by the end of the night (PST).

Comment: I have added an example to the very bottom of my post, hopefully that can help resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you copy the tasks.json to the root of Invoke-Test.ps1?

Comment: From my research it wouldn't run any tests then, it requires to be in the .vscode folder. Also as note the tasks.json file was created using the workspace generation, so it created the folder and tasks.json for me automatically. The only thing I changed was moving the install-module-locally.ps1 (I have tried other places too) into the folder. However, to answer your question, I moved it into the folder you suggested, and no task executions were attempted, and it instead tried to execute the ${file} which ended in an error because the module doesn't exist, hence the task for install.

Comment: Seems like bug with `preLaunchTask` not working from workspace file.  I've seen a couple issues on Github about it.  Try moving the configurations section out of the workspace file into a `.vscode\launch.json file`.  This worked for me

Comment: Ah ha! I got it working with your suggestion @Daniel. I modified it a bit but it is working enough to consider this solved. Did you want me to go ahead and post the answer to this or did you want to (if you don't by morning I will close it out with the answer)? I have also made a new branch to the github repo above with the changes I made to view the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel) for his comment on the original post I have managed to get it working.

> Seems like bug with preLaunchTask not working from workspace file.
> I've seen a couple issues on Github about it. Try moving the
> configurations section out of the workspace file into a
> .vscode\launch.json file. This worked for me

I have also pushed a new branch to the example repository so all differences can be seen.

1. [Original Error Example](https://github.com/lzinga/vscode-tasks-error/tree/main)
2. [Working Example](https://github.com/lzinga/vscode-tasks-error/tree/working)

The issue appears to be from within the `workspace.code-workspace` not working correctly. I moved the .vscode folder into the workspace directory and separated the launch configuration into its own file `launch.json` and the task started executing as expected.